# React Navigation update screen on specific tab

Tags: react-native, react-redux, react-navigation

I'm new on react native. I have navigation (bottom navigation) with Setting screen and TopNavigation.
Inside TopNavigation I have dynamic tab with 1 screen (multiple tab with 1 screen). The problem is, `MainComponent.js` would receive the results at `componentWillReceiveProps()` and how to send or update data from `nextProps` to my specific dynamic tab? Or maybe my code in the wrong way?

You can see my image, my multiple tab with 1 screen, and have 1 button to fetch data. And this is my code:

> index.js
>
> ```
> import React from 'react';
> import {AppRegistry} from 'react-native';
> import {name as appName} from './app.json';
> //Redux
> import {applyMiddleware, createStore} from 'redux';
> import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
> //reducers
> import allReducers from './App/reducers';
> import MainContainer from './App/Containers/MainContainer';
> //Redux saga
> import createSagaMiddleware from 'redux-saga';
> import rootSaga from './App/sagas/rootSaga';
>
> const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware();
>
> let store = createStore(allReducers, applyMiddleware(sagaMiddleware));
>
> const Main = () => (
>     <Provider store={store}>
>         <MainContainer />
>     </Provider>
> );
> sagaMiddleware.run(rootSaga);
> AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => Main);
> ```
>
> MainContainer.js
>
> ```
> import {connect} from 'react-redux';
> import MainComponent from '../Components/MainComponent';
> import {fetchCategoriesAction} from '../actions/categoriesAction';
> import {fetchTestAction} from "../actions/testAction";
>
> const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
>     return {
>         receivedCategories: state.categoriesReducer,
>         receivedMovies: state.testingReducer,
>         navigation: state.navigation
>     }
> };
> const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
>     return {
>         onFetchCategories: (payload) => {
>             console.log("mapDispatchToProps");
>             dispatch(fetchCategoriesAction(payload));
>         },
>         onFetchTest: (payload) => {
>             dispatch(fetchTestAction(payload))
>         }
>     };
> };
> const MainContainer = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(MainComponent);
> export default MainContainer;
> ```
>
> MainComponent.js
>
> ```
> import React, {Component} from "react";
> import {createAppContainer, createMaterialTopTabNavigator} from 'react-navigation'
> import {createMaterialBottomTabNavigator} from "react-navigation-material-bottom-tabs";
> import {tabBarOptions} from "../Navigation/Top/Options";
> import Test from "./Screens/Test";
> import Setting from "./Screens/Setting";
>
> export default class MainComponent extends Component {
>
>     constructor(props) {
>         super(props);
>         this.state = {myNavigator: null, movies: [], categories: []}
>     }
>
>     componentWillMount() {
>         this.props.onFetchCategories({p1: 1});
>     }
>
>     createNavigator(categories) {
>         if (categories != null) {
>             const screens = {};
>             categories.forEach(page => {
>                 screens[page.slug] = {
>                     screen: Test,
>                 };
>             });
>
>             let TopNavigator = createMaterialTopTabNavigator(screens, {
>                 tabBarOptions,
>                 lazy: true,
>             });
>
>             const AppNavigator = createMaterialBottomTabNavigator({
>                 B1: TopNavigator,
>                 B2: Setting,
>             });
>             const AppContainer = createAppContainer(AppNavigator);
>             this.setState({myNavigator: <AppContainer screenProps={this.props}/>});
>         }
>     }
>
>
>     componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
>         console.log(nextProps);
>         if (nextProps.receivedCategories !== null && nextProps.receivedCategories.categories !== this.state.categories) {
>             this.setState({categories: nextProps.receivedCategories.categories});
>             this.createNavigator(nextProps.receivedCategories.categories)
>         }
>     }
>
>     render() {
>         return this.state.myNavigator;
>     }
>
> }
> ```
>
> Test.js
>
> ```
> import React, {Component} from "react";
> import {Text, Container, Button} from 'native-base'
> export default class Test extends Component {
>     constructor(props) {
>         super(props);
>     }
>
>     render() {
>
>         return (
>             <Container>
>                 <Button onPress={ () => {
>                     this.props.screenProps.onFetchTest({slug: this.props.navigation.state.routeName})
>                 }}><Text>Fetch Data</Text></Button>
>                 <Text>Test screen {this.props.navigation.state.routeName}</Text>
>                 <Text>I want this part changed when i click fetch data button</Text>
>             </Container>
>         )
>     }
> }
> ```

[image: Tab lounge][image: Tab news]

Thank you!